# QML Import Path Run Time issues with Qt 6

Tags: qt, qml

I am lost on how Qt decides the qml import locations at run time.

For example. If my folder structure is as follows:

```
MyApp
CMakeLists.txt
MyQmlModule
CMakeList.txt
```

No problem. dont need to do anything extra the qml module from MyQmlModule is loaded by just linking the library in the MyApp CMakeLists.txt

Now if I add a Organization folder between MyApp and MyQmlModule everything breaks.

```
MyApp
CMakeLists.txt
 QmlModules
   MyQmlModule
   CMakeList.txt
```

To get it to work in the above structure I need to do two things

1. add to the the CMakeList.txt of the module a QML_IMPORT_PATH to be the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../ it has to be the parent (QmlModules) dir for Qt Creator to pick up on it. This allows syntax completion / highlighting during development
2. in main.cpp engine->addImportPath( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

#2 is my problem I shouldn't have to add this to my production code to just find my qml module. I assumed this would be covered in #1 in the cmake file but doesnt seem to take.

Last thought is, I thought that the qt_add_qml_module function in cmake creates .qrc file that was compiled as part of the the plugin? If thats not true do I need to install all my assets along side the plugin?

Here is an example:

Folder Structure:

- testapp

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - main.cpp
  - Main.qml
  - modules

    - mymodule

      - CMakeLists.txt
      - CustomQMl.qml

testapp CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(testapp VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

qt_add_executable(apptestapp
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(apptestapp
    URI testapp
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

set_target_properties(apptestapp PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(apptestapp
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    mymodule
)

install(TARGETS apptestapp
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
# adding custom module
add_subdirectory(modules/mymodule)
```

testapp main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  QObject::connect(
      &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed, &app,
      []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

  // have to add this import path or it wont load module
  engine.addImportPath(
      "/home/developer/testapp/builds/"
      "build-testapp-Desktop_Qt_6_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/modules");
  engine.loadFromModule("testapp", "Main");

  return app.exec();
}
```

modules/mymodule CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MyModuleProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

qt_add_qml_module(mymodule
    URI mymodule
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES CustomQml.qml
)

set_target_properties(mymodule PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

set(QML_DIRS "${QML_IMPORT_PATH}")
list(APPEND QML_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../")
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_DIRS}" CACHE STRING "Controls" FORCE)
```

as you can see in the example above I need to add the import path at runtime to the build dir to have it find the plugin module and load it. If I cut out the "modules" dir I can remote the line to import qml from the main.cpp and I have to adjust the QML_IMPORT_PATH to be just the ${CAMKE_CURRENT_BINART_DIR} for qt creator to pick up on it. I believe the problem to be that the QML_IMPORT_PATH is set differently between qt creator and runtime there for my QML_IMPORT_PATH I added in the cmake is not even used during runtime. I have checked my qt creator settings and yes that carry over env variable from the build env to the runtime which would include QML_IMPORT_PATH. In the past I would something like this in the main.cpp Q_INIT_RESOURCE(pathtoqrcfile.qrc) and then add the qrc:/.... as the qml import path. This to me is acceptable because I know when I release I will release with that qrc not the build dir as its doing with qt 6.5.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @JarMan I updated the description above with an example